# Unable to install LDT to Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14.0)

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I was setting up a new laptop and downloaded Eclipse: Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0) but when I tried to add the LDT plugins, it fails because it cannot satisfy dependency (see below.)

The prior version of eclipse I had on my last laptop was 2018-12 (4.10.)

Does anyone have a list of what or know which the last/latest version of Eclipse which works with the (1.4.2?) LDT plugin is?

[[EDIT]] => Verified that Lua Development Tools still installs if I reinstall 2018-12 Eclipse. So it is a compatability thing as I asked. Since no one yet has the answer, I will install one after another Eclipse version to determine last that works and update this entry. VERIFIED: 2019-09 is the latest that works with LDT plugin.

(pointed repo to "stable" (although tried even nightly after that)
Error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Lua Development Tools SDK 1.4.2.201804031433 (org.eclipse.ldt.source.feature.group 1.4.2.201804031433)
Missing requirement: Lua Development Tools Core 1.3.0.201804031433 (org.eclipse.ldt 1.3.0.201804031433) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.dltk.core [5.5.0,6.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Lua Development Tools - Core Feature 1.4.2.201804031433 (org.eclipse.ldt.core.feature.group 1.4.2.201804031433)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ldt [1.3.0.201804031433,1.3.0.201804031433]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Lua Development Tools 1.4.2.201804031433 (org.eclipse.ldt.feature.group 1.4.2.201804031433)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ldt.core.feature.group [1.4.2.201804031433,1.4.2.201804031433]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Lua Development Tools SDK 1.4.2.201804031433 (org.eclipse.ldt.source.feature.group 1.4.2.201804031433)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ldt.feature.group [1.4.2.201804031433,1.4.2.201804031433]
```

Comment: How are you trying to add it? What do you mean by "stable"--is that referring to a URL? Are you letting Eclipse check all of the know update sites?

Comment: I am sorry, I seemed to have left out the link to the repos I had intended to be there:  https://wiki.eclipse.org/LDT/User_Area/updatesites.  The "stable" reference was just which of the versions to pull plugins from (note, even "Nightly" points to same version of plugin). -- And yes, I tried "all sites" but it was a fresh install, so all sites = default on fresh install + the LDT stable site.

Comment: The default lost of sites can vary depending on what you downloaded. If you don't have download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-12 in the list of available sites, it needs to be added.

Comment: I have: [base=http://download.eclipse.org] releases/2019-12, ldt/releases/stable,updates/4.14, usssdk/updates/release/latest, releases/latest  (please pardon any typos)  -- but are you just giving general advice or are you saying you got it working with your own 4.14/2019-12 release?

Comment: Curious. Try appending a '/' at the end of the URLs.

Comment: Will do (sorry, hit enter out of habit on line before so was cut off and had to edit)

Comment: more: mpc/releases/1.81 [EDIT] --> Oops adding the "/" at end then apply/close ende dup REMOVING all the ones I edited from my Software sites... grrr... oh well, will find out where this stuff is saved and delete the prefs to reset...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205568/discussion-between-varsuuk-and-nitind).

Comment: @nitind It is the requirement for a version of org.eclipse.dltk.core less than 6.0 that is causing the issue - 2019-12 has version 6.0

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for the reasoning behind 2019-09->2019-12 fail. If you could repost as "answer" (I'm new to doing anything other than reading posts) then I can mark it as the :"answer" since it is a better answer than my own where I indicate which version last works. Yours give the "why" of it. Hopefully, it will be updated in future so I can continue to use LDT with newer Eclipse's Eclipsi? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key error here is

```
requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.dltk.core [5.5.0,6.0.0)'
```

which is saying that a version of the 'org.eclipse.dltk.core' plug-in (bundle in OSGi terminology) with a version of at least 5.5.0 and **less than** 6.0.0 is required.

The Eclipse 2019-12 release has version 6.0 of this plug-in so it does not match the criteria and the install fails.

Comment: Do you know how/where I might find out if it will be updated to work with 6.0. I am new to updating Eclipse more than once a year or two ;) I will stick to 2019-09 which this plug-in works until there is an update for LDT or another Lua plugin is made available. Thank you again for the answer.

Comment: You can look at the LDT web site [here](https://www.eclipse.org/ldt/) but there doesn't seem to have been much activity lately. You can create a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=LDT;component=LuaDevelopmentTools)

Answer (score 0):

I installed earlier versions of Eclipse IDE (Java) and it appears the version right before the one I was trying (2019-12) is the last that will accept installing the LDT plug-in successfully: Eclipse (Java) 2019-09

Hopefully it is a bug that gets fixed in either LDT or Eclipse 2019-12.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that I found here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1101907/

The solution is basically to provide the missing resource from a download since it doesn't seem to be available from repositories any more:

Download the runtime for DLTK 5.7.1 as a zip: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/dltk/downloads/drops/R5.7/R-5.7.1-201703020501/dltk-core-R-5.7.1-201703020501.zip

In Eclipse, navigate to menu > Help > Install new software...

Click Manage... to go to Available Software Sites dialog

Click Add... use a good name like "LDTK zip", click the "Archive" button and browse to that zip, downloaded from before.

Then when I tried again the install happened correctly and my initial tests indicate that LDT is working as expected.